# How to pass props in the modal in react

Tags: reactjs

I am creating my first react project, i am using GitHub api to fetch user and display them firstly in card view then on clicking on more button to any profile i want to create a modal using [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) in react till now i am able to create an modal but now i am not getting how to get data to that modal coponent

Here is my App.js

```
    import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
    import Users from './components/users/Users';
    import User from './components/users/User';
    import Modal from './components/Modal/Modal'
    import Search from './components/users/Search';
    import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';
    import About from './components/pages/About';
    import axios from 'axios';

    import './App.css';

    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        users: [],
        user: {},
        loading: false,
        alert: null,
        modal: {},
      }



      // get users from Search.js
      searchUsers = async text => {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        const res = await axios.get(
          `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${
          process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
          }&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`);

        this.setState({ users: res.data.items, loading: false })
        console.log(text);
      }

      //get single profile
      getUser = async username => {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        const res = await axios.get(
          `https://api.github.com/users/${username}?client_id=${
          process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
          }&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`);

        this.setState({ user: res.data, loading: false });
        this.setState({ modal: res.data, loadading: false });
      }



      //clear search
      clearUsers = () => this.setState({ users: [], loading: false });

      setAlert = (msg, type) => {
        this.setState({ alert: { msg: msg, type: type } });

        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ alert: null }), 5000);
      };

      render() {
        return (

          <Router>
            <div className='App'>
              <Navbar />
              <div className="container">
                <Alert alert={this.state.alert} />
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/'
                    render={props => (
                      <Fragment>
                        <Search
                          searchUsers={this.searchUsers}
                          clearUsers={this.clearUsers}
                          showClear={this.state.users.length > 0 ? true : false}
                          setAlert={this.setAlert}
                        />
                        <Users loading={this.state.loading} users={this.state.users} />
                      </Fragment>
                    )} />
                  <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                  <Route path='/user/:login' render={props => (
                    <User {...props} getUser={this.getUser} user={this.state.user} loading={this.state.loading} />
                  )} />

                  <Route path='/modal/:login' render={props => (
                    <Modal {...props} getUser={this.getUser} modal={this.state.modal} loading={this.state.loading} />
                  )} />

                </Switch>

              </div>
            </div>

          </Router>

        );
      }

    }

    export default App;


here is my Modal.js



import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal');

export default class Modal extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.el = document.createElement('div');
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
    };
    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        modalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
    };

    render() {


        const {
            children,
            name,
            avatar_url,
            location,
            bio,
            blog,
            followers,
            following,
            public_repos,
        } = this.props.modal;

        const { loading } = this.props;
        if (loading) return <Spinner />
        return (


            ReactDom.createPortal(children, this.el)

        )

    }
}
```

any guide would be appriciated thanks in advance

Comment: In this code you pass them

<Modal {...props} getUser={this.getUser} modal={this.state.modal} loading={this.state.loading} />

what is difficulties?

Comment: @DmitryReutov i didn't get you please can you elaborate what you are trying to say

Comment: i think you should pass them as in any other component
just mention props in constructor
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.el = document.createElement('div');
    }
or i didnt get your question then i'm sorry

Comment: @DmitryReutov can you show me somewhere  how it works actually i am quite new learning things so i didn't get it may be i am doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the props already to Modal.

In Modal, do something like

```
Class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(){
     super(props);
  }
  render(){
    const {
      modal,
      getUser,
      loading,
      anyOtherPropYouPassIn
    } = this.props;

    const { loading } = this.props;
    if (loading) return <Spinner />
    return (
        ReactDom.createPortal(children, this.el)
    )
}
```

Comment: is it related to the props? what are they?

Comment: @Susheel constructor(props){
     super(props);
  }

Comment: actually i want to show the data to the model that i am passing through the app.js i hav first created simple pafge to show the data but now i am thinking of doing it with the modal so trying it like this

Comment: i understand your requirement. My example should conceptually work. The idea is to read the props passed into the Modal component (this.props) which is an object containing all the props you passed as key value pairs. So you can just read from this.prop.yourData. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component - this article might be a useful read. It's essentially the same as passing props to any other child component.

Comment: if you need to see my code you an see it at https://github.com/avinashcodemymobile/gitfinder

Comment: had a look, the modal component still looks the same as in your question. It might be more helpful if you paste the stacktrace or the exact error that is showing up.

Comment: Target container is not a DOM element.
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
Modal.render
src/components/Modal/Modal.js:32
  29 | 
  30 | const { loading } = this.props;
  31 | if (loading) return <Spinner />
> 32 | return (
     | ^  33 | 
  34 |     ReactDom.createPortal(children, this.el)
  35 | 
View compiled